# Can I use 'rather adjective to' instead of 'too adjective to'?

Tags: meaning, phrases

My question is contained in the title: can I use 'rather (an adjective) to' instead of 'too (an adjective) to'?

To convey a weaker tone than a sentence such as 'Its implications are too various to outline in this short preamble', can I write like this: 'Its implications are rather various to outline in this short preamble'?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is yes.

e.g. 
"He is rather old to be doing that".

He is doing it, and it is unexpected and unusual that he is.  It's a descriptive statement.

"He is too old to be doing that".

He is doing it, and he should not be doing it.  It is a proscriptive statement.

However, in the specific example you ask about, the answer is no.   "...rather various..." is not a phrase in use.